# A set that is bounded below possess a subsequence that converges to its infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is nonempty and bounded below. Show that there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{ n\in \mathbb{N}}\in S^{\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $S$ converging to $\inf(S)$.

Comment: Do you have any characterizations for the infimum or just the definition, that is, the largest lower bound?

Comment: Why do you think that the idea of compactness is useful here? The question doesn't mention compactness of $S$ anywhere at all as of now.

Comment: @Error404 I thought it might be useful.

Comment: @clark just the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ denote the infimum of $S$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, the quantity $s+\epsilon$ cannot be a lower-bound for $S$. Hence, there exists (see the note below if not clear) $x_\epsilon \in S$ such that
$$
s\leq x_\epsilon < s+\epsilon.
$$
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and using $\epsilon = 1/n$ in the above, we obtain $x_n \in S$ such that
$$
s \leq x_n < s + \frac{1}{n}.
$$
By the squeeze theorem, it follows that $x_n \to s$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Note**: If $s+\epsilon$ is *not* a lower bound for $S$, this means that the statement
$$
s+\epsilon \leq x, \quad \forall x \in S
$$
is false. Put otherwise, there must exist $x \in S$ for which the above fails, i.e. such that $x < s+ \epsilon$. But, because $s$ is a lower bound for $S \ni x$, we still have $s \leq x$.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by $\epsilon:=n?$

Comment: The procedure used to construct $x_\epsilon$ works for each $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, it works for every natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Repeating this for each $n$ gives you the sequence $(x_n)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: @rolandcyp I believe MathEnthusiant's comment is about your definition of $\epsilon$. Should it not be $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\epsilon = n$?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Thanks!